# Passing more than a Bundle to a fragment [Android]

Tags: android, fragment, bundle

Is it possible to combine two bundles into one before passing to a fragment on Android? 
So code snippet would be similar to :

```
  Bundle b1 = SomeClass1.getSomeBundle();
  Bundle b2 = SomeClass2.getDifferentBundle();
  // How to do I pass these two bundles to a fragment?
  fragment.setArgument(b1 + b2); // Illustrative only.
```

Comment: why having 2 different bundle? instead of one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible to combine two bundles into one before passing to a
>   fragment on Android?

Yes, you can do it using  [Bundle.putAll(Bundle bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

Or you can pass both bundles separately by creating a Bundle using  [Bundle.putBundle(String key, Bundle value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

Comment: I've read that `putAll()` will override the existing Bundle. But whatever, `putBundle()` seems to be the better way to go!

Comment: @BarthyB.: Yes if you have different keys in both bundle then use `putAll` other-wise use `putBundle`

Comment: Does putAll() have the same effect as if there was only one bundle? Or do I need to remember that I passed multiple bundles.

Comment: @user3079275: please explain more

Comment: I have two bundles with different keys, so I suppose the effect of putAll() will be as if I passed in a bundle that is bundle1 + bundle2 right? If so I need to use putAll()

Answer (score 0):

`Bundle` can contains also `Bundle`. You can use [putBundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putBundle(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle))

```
 Bundle b1 = SomeClass1.getSomeBundle();
 Bundle b2 = SomeClass2.getDifferentBundle();
 b1.putBundle("b2", b2);
 fragment.setArgument(b1);
```

to retrieve it, you can use [getBundle(String key)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String))

```
  Bundle b1 = getArguments();
  Bundle b2 = b1.getBundle("b2");
```

Answer (score 0):

Bundle can contains Bundle

```
Bundle mainBundle = new Bundle();
Bundle b1 = SomeClass1.getSomeBundle();
Bundle b2 = SomeClass2.getDifferentBundle();

mainBundle.putBundle("b1", b1);
mainBundle.putBundle("b2", b2);

fragment.setArgument(mainBundle);
```

And to get the bundle from a bundle just call :

```
Bundle b1 = mainBundle.getBundle("b1");
Bundle b2 = mainBundle.getBundle("b2");
```